# Scrapyのmiddlewareの設定について

Tags: python

ScrapyでHTTPCACHE_ENABLEDをTrueとした設定を行いたいのですが、設定方法がわかりません。

Scrapyの設定に関するドキュメント(https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/downloader-middleware.html)をよんだのですが、例として以下の設定をしましょうしか記載がないのでその後どのようにHTTPCACHE_ENABLEDをTrueとした設定をどこで行うのか不明です。

例）

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.CustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
}
```

- もう少し掘り下げた説明
- 設定の例
- 参考になるサイト
- そもそも論の説明

等記載いただけたら幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

ここですね。
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/settings.html#populating-the-settings

`scrapy startproject hoge` で始めたのなら、`settings.py`があるのでそれを書き換えれば（コメントになっているのを解除すれば）いいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。settings.pyの中身を確認しコメント解除で変更できました。